# using number filter in custom filter Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am creating a custom filter for numbers in Angular 1.5 and I need to use the existing number filter in it. 
I have this number format 3445 and I need to convert it to 3'445. For this purpose, first, I need to pass the input number to the number filter,

3445.05252 -> 3,445.1 -> 3'445.1

The problem is that I don't know how to use the number filter in my filter function. Here is my code:

```
 app.filter('tick', function () {
      return function(input, $number) {
        var number =$number(input,1);
        return number.toString().replace(",","'");
};
```

});

I can not use it like 3445.05252 | number:1 | tick. It must be with the number filter inside my filter.

here it is with $filter injected:

```
app.filter('tick', function () {
return function(input, $filter) {
        var number = $filter('number')(input,1);
    return number.toString().replace(",","'");
};
```

});

Here is the html code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
       <p> {{ 245258.222| tick }}  </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my js code:

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

 app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) { 
        $scope.price=2355;
        $scope.url="http://google.com";
  }]);
app.filter('tick', function () {
return function(input, $filter) {
        var numberFilter= $filter('number');
        var number =numberFilter(input,1);
    return number.toString().replace(",","'");
};
 });
```

Comment: you tried inject *$filter* service? and use *$filter('number')?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The poster has updated the question so I'm adding another answer.

You can inject `$filter` into your own filter. This will allow you to retrieve the `number` filter by name and use it however you like.

### Example:

```
app.filter('tick', function ($filter) {
    return function(input) {
        var numberFilter = $filter('number');
        var filteredInput = numberFilter(input, 1);
        return filteredInput.toString().replace(",", "'");
    };
});
```

Then in the HTML you can just say...
`3445.05252 | tick`

Comment: When I try   <p> {{ 245258.222|tick}}  </p> , I also get  {{ 245258.222|tick}} . Something is not working.

Comment: I am trying this in JS Fiddle first and I don't know if I can see the console here, but I have pasted the whole code so you can see it.

Comment: Oops I forgot to return a function. In your example you're injecting $filter into the wrong place.

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help (even if I did make a few mistakes haha).

Answer (score 1):

### You can apply multiple filters in angularJS using piping.

Instead of trying to inject `$number` into your function, just apply both filters to your data in the HTML.

e.g.
`3445.05252 | number | thick`

This will apply the number filter, then pass the result of that into your `thick` function.

Result: `3'445.1`

Comment: I have posted another answer